# Find list of items(fruits) from an array in an array of object and calculate its quantity and push into another array as an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How to loop through the array of objects fruitsnveggies and compare them against the variable fruits and veggies to filter and sum up the values based on the arrays.

I want to create an array of object called totalproduce containing the sum of all quantities of fruits, veggies and others. I tried to loop through the variable fruitsnveggies using a forloop and used if/else conditions to appropriately match to the values from array called fruits, veggies and the leftover elements into others. The issue is I am not sure if I am doing it correctly or is there is a better way to do it.

```
var fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "mango"]

var veggies = ["carrots", "onions", "brocoli"]

var fruitsnveggies = [
    { "item": "apples", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "oranges", "quantity": 2},
    { "item": "carrots", "quantity": 5},
    { "item": "mango", "quantity": 2},
    { "item": "brocoli", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "chillipowder", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "onions", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "ketchup", "quantity": 1},
]

for(var i=0; i<fruitsnveggies.length; i++){
   if(fruitsnveggies[i]["item"] === fruits[i]){
      //Code here
   }else if(fruitsnveggies[i]["item"] === fruits[i]){
      //Code here
   }else{
     //Code here
   }
}
```

Expected output should be as shown below

```
var totalproduce = [
  {"items": "fruits", "quantity": 7},
  {"items": "veggies", "quantity": 11},
  {"items": "others", "quantity": 4}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `for` loop, which I think is easier to understand and an ES6 simple `filter` your `totalproduce` variable would be filled like:

```
var fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "mango"];

var veggies = ["carrots", "onions", "brocoli"];

var fruitsnveggies = [
    { "item": "apples", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "oranges", "quantity": 2},
    { "item": "carrots", "quantity": 5},
    { "item": "mango", "quantity": 2},
    { "item": "brocoli", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "chillipowder", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "onions", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "ketchup", "quantity": 1},
];

var totalproduce = [
    {"items": "fruits", "quantity": 0},
    {"items": "veggies", "quantity": 0},
    {"items": "others", "quantity": 0}
]

for(var i=0; i < fruitsnveggies.length; i++) {
    var element = fruitsnveggies[i];
    var isAFruit = fruits.find(fruit => fruit == element.item[0]);
    if (isAFruit) {
        totalproduce.items[0].quantity++;
    }
    else {
        var isAVeggie = veggies.find(veggie => veggie == element.item[0]);
        if (isAVeggie) {
            totalproduce.items[1].quantity++;
        }
        else {
            totalproduce.items[2].quantity++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work for several reasons:

- You are checking for equality of the `item` property with a string at a specific index  in the `fruits` array. This will break once the index goes out of bounds of the `fruits` array. It will also only check if the `item` in question is equal to one of the items in `fruits` and not any of them.
- You are referencing `fruits` again in you second condition, when I think you mean to reference `veggies`.

Here is a better working solution:

```js
const fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "mango"]

const veggies = ["carrots", "onions", "brocoli"]

const fruitsnveggies = [
    { "item": "apples", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "oranges", "quantity": 2},
    { "item": "carrots", "quantity": 5},
    { "item": "mango", "quantity": 2},
    { "item": "brocoli", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "chillipowder", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "onions", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "ketchup", "quantity": 1},
]

const totalProduce = {
  "fruits": 0,
  "veggies": 0,
  "other" : 0
}

fruitsnveggies.forEach(
  (produce) => {
    if (fruits.includes(produce["item"])) {
      totalProduce["fruits"] = totalProduce["fruits"] + produce["quantity"];
    } else if (veggies.includes(produce["item"])) {
      totalProduce["veggies"] = totalProduce["veggies"] + produce["quantity"];
    } else {
      totalProduce["other"] = totalProduce["other"] + produce["quantity"];
    }
  }
);

console.log(totalProduce);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it something like this using the ES6 functions `Array.reduce` and `Array.includes`.

```js
var fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "mango"]
    
var veggies = ["carrots", "onions", "brocoli"]

var fruitsnveggies = [
  { "item": "apples", "quantity": 3},
  { "item": "oranges", "quantity": 2},
  { "item": "carrots", "quantity": 5},
  { "item": "mango", "quantity": 2},
  { "item": "brocoli", "quantity": 3},
  { "item": "chillipowder", "quantity": 3},
  { "item": "onions", "quantity": 3},
  { "item": "ketchup", "quantity": 1},
]

var totalProduce = fruitsnveggies.reduce((map, next) => {
  if (fruits.includes(next.item))
      map.fruits += next.quantity;
  else if (veggies.includes(next.item))
      map.veggies += next.quantity;
  else map.other += next.quantity;
  return map
}, { fruits: 0, veggies: 0, other: 0 })

console.log(totalProduce)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Franky238/ex1johgu/16/) to avoid long `forEach`es and `for`s and other. With `filter`, and `reduce` you can do powerful things. Look methods for `Array` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2)

```
const fruits = ["apples", "oranges", "mango"]

const veggies = ["carrots", "onions", "brocoli"]

const fruitsnveggies = [
    { "item": "apples", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "oranges", "quantity": 2},
    { "item": "carrots", "quantity": 5},
    { "item": "mango", "quantity": 2},
    { "item": "brocoli", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "chillipowder", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "onions", "quantity": 3},
    { "item": "ketchup", "quantity": 1}
];

const onlyVegies = fruitsnveggies
  .filter(a => veggies.includes(a.item))
  .reduce((acc, val) => {
    return {
      item: "veggies",
      quantity: acc.quantity + val.quantity,
    }
  }, {item: "veggies", quantity: 0});

const onlyFruits = fruitsnveggies
  .filter(a => fruits.includes(a.item))
  .reduce((acc, val) => {
    return {
        item: "fruits",
      quantity: acc.quantity + val.quantity,
    }
  }, {item: "fruits", quantity: 0});

  const others = fruitsnveggies
    .filter(a => !fruits.includes(a.item) && !veggies.includes(a.item))
    .reduce((acc, val) => {
      return {
        item: "others",
        quantity: acc.quantity + val.quantity,
      }
    }, {item: "others", quantity: 0});

  console.log("result: ", [onlyVegies, onlyFruits, others])
```